# How does IPv6 and AAAA DNS records affect my visitors?

Tags: dns, visitors, ipv6

If I set up a web site and the web server only has IPv6, and my domain uses a AAAA DNS record instead of a A record, how does this affect my visitors?

Can only end users that have IPv6 on their client access my web site? if that is the case, is there any work arounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users without an IPv6 connection will not have the possibility to connect to your server. There will be some workarounds such as using a [tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers) or IPv6 proxies.

<s>Normally it should not affect any of your visitors but there can be a few cases in which an AAAA-record is requested only (so the user does only get the IPv6 address) but the connection does not support IPv6 already thus making the website unaccessible for some users (this may affect 1 or 2 in 1000 users).</s>

Comment: 1 or 2 in 1000? Here in Sweden IPv6 is very rare, and the biggest telecom company Telia sadly don't support IPv6. Okey, so they can not access the web site then, that was what I presumed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Jonas: 1 or 2 in 2000 will see the problem mentioned in which the the website is not available despite the fact that there is an IPv4 *and* IPv6 address in the DNS. This is because the program "thinks" there is IPv6 available at this connection and requests the IPv6 address but fails to make a connection. Most times it'll be fine if the connection only supports IPv4.

Comment: But the question was about **IPv6 only** in case the server doesn't have IPv4.

Comment: @Jonas Ok, I misinterpreted your question, I'll change my answer reflecting this information.